# How do I enable the microphone on the Surface Pro 4 (touch) keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, microphone, microsoft-surface-pro

Having used an iPad and Android for several years with their excellent speech recognition available from the microphone of the on-screen keyboard, I'm stumped that I can't find the same thing on my new Surface Pro 4!

Is it possible to have arbitrary voice input available via the virtual keyboard, as with iOS and Android?

**Edit:** Cortana is working, and the voice recognition is excellent with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!? Discussed at https://www.engadget.com/2018/04/27/windows-10-s-next-major-update-arrives-on-april-30th/:

> Other notable features include tweaks to Microsoft Edge, such as tab muting and autofill on web payment forms, and **updates to Dictation. Instead of seeking out the voice input app, you'll now be able to capture spoken word in any text field simply by pressing Win+H**

I just typed windows H and this text is now being recognized as I speak it.

Answer (score 0):

Voice typing as a feature of the touch keyboard, at time of writing, does not exist within Windows.

Speech dictation exists, but it's not the same way that the iPad integrates it, and is treated as an accessibility feature rather than a part of the touch keyboard.

[Instructions to enable it are here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/getstarted-use-speech-recognition)

Or simply open search/Cortana and type `Windows Speech Recognition`

Personally I've never found it as good or reliable as the Google or iPad options, and it's actually designed to be able to do a lot more than simply typing.

[Further reading on voice commands](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/common-speech-recognition-commands#1TC=windows-7)

[Further reading on speech dictation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dictate-text-speech-recognition#1TC=windows-7)